# How to set "simulation setup" to use IDA in OpenModelica?

Tags: optimization, solver, ida, openmodelica

I am going to perform sensitivity analysis on a model developed in OpenModelica. Based on the link below I intended to do it via IDA:

https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/parametersensitivity.html

I set the "simulation setup" as it is advised in this link, but unfortunately I get failed in simulating the model; the error is shown below:

### IDA## set IDASensInit failed!

I'd appreciate if you could help me with this regard and of course if you provide me with a document in more detail using IDAS in OM.

Thanks and regards,
Amir

Comment: You could also try the new OMSens feature:) It is a module dedicated to sensitivity analysis

Comment: Which version are you using? I've just managed to run the sensitivity computation on the `LotkaVolterra` example from the User guide you cite (with OM 1.16.2 on Linux). Only issue: I get a lexer error when trying ` plot($Sensitivities.lambda1.x)` "Lexer failed to recognize '$Sensitivit'". However, `plotAll()` does work and it shows the `$Sensitivities.*` variables.